# Google Scripts fileIterator issues

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to access sub folders using google script's DriveApp folderIterator however it's not reading the child folders correctly.

For example my drive has this structure:

```
+Root
   +High School
       +Class Material
          -File1
          -File2
       +Books

function test(){
    var folderIter = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("High School");
    var folder = folderIter.next();
    printFolder(folder);
}

function printFolder(folder){
    var folderIter = folder.getFoldersByName("Class Material");
    while (folderIter.hasNext()) { //  always returning false
        var file = folderIter.next();
        Logger.log(file.getName());
    }
}
```

The condition in my while loop is always returning false when it should be reading the folder "Class Material"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: It was an issue with the folders that were shared with me, multiple folders with the same name.

Comment: Maybe the folder iterator is returning a different "High School" folder. Add an auxiliary function to check how many High School folders you have access.

Comment: Have you debugged your script at all? If so, why haven't you shared those results? What's the ID of the folder you are getting? Is it the correct folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
function test(){
    var folderIter = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("High School");
    var folder = folderIter.next();
    printFolder(folder);
}

function printFolder(folder){
  // get folders under High School
  var folders = folder.getFolders();
  while( folders.hasNext() ) {
    var subFolder = folders.next();
    if( subFolder.getName() ===  "Class Material" ) {
      // what every you want to do with subFolder
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: folders.hasNext() always returns false even though in the drive folder, there are other folders within it

Comment: As @Ruben said are there more than 1 High School folders?

Comment: No there is only one high school folder, I called "hasNext" on the high school folder iterator. Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried my code for a folder set up similar to your description Tester1 with SubTester1 & SubTester2 and it works fine.  Do you have permissions to view all the folders you mentioned?